# Install Python from Powershell script

Tags: python, windows, powershell

The following command successfully installs Python on Windows 11 when run from the PowerShell command line as Administrator:

```
c:/temp/python-3.11.4-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 InstallLauncherAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0
```

But when that same command is placed inside a script `myinstallscript.ps1`, and when that script is called from the PowerShell command line as `.\myinstallscript.ps1` , the installation fails without throwing any error.

Here is the relevant script code, including the same command that does not work when it is invoked in a script:

```
Write-Output "About to create temp folder. "
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\temp

Write-Output "About to set security protocol. "
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Write-Output "About to download Python executable to temp folder. "
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.4/python-3.11.4-amd64.exe" -OutFile "c:/temp/python-3.11.4-amd64.exe"

Write-Output "About to install Python. "
c:/temp/python-3.11.4-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 InstallLauncherAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0

Write-Output "About to append python to path temporarily. "
$env:Path += ";$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Programs\Python\Python311\;$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\"
```

What specific syntax needs to be used in `myinstallscript.ps1` in order to successfully execute the `c:/temp/python-3.11.4-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 InstallLauncherAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0` command?  And what specific syntax would be needed in order for the command to gracefully break the program with a useful error message in the event that the installation fails for some unforeseen reason?

Comment: @mklement0 `Start-Process -Wait c:/temp/python-3.11.4-amd64.exe '/quiet InstallAllUsers=0 InstallLauncherAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0'` works.  Can you suggest a solution to [this downstream problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76871462/set-itemproperty-is-failing-to-add-item-to-path)?

Answer (score 1):

- When PowerShell calls *external programs* (such as `python-3.11.4-amd64.exe`), it reports their process *exit code* via the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode). By convention, external programs signal *success* with value `0`, and *failure* with any nonzero exit code.
- However, PowerShell is only able to report the exit code if the external program executes *synchronously* (i.e., it blocks the caller until the program terminates), whereas **PowerShell executes *GUI(-subsystem)* applications *asynchronously* by default** (i.e., it launches the external program and immediately returns control to the caller).

*Installers* such as `python-3.11.4-amd64.exe` are typically GUI applications,  so **extra effort is needed to make the call *synchronous***, so that your script (a) awaits completion of the installation and (b) can check for success vs. failure via `$LASTEXITCODE`.

There are several ways to make invocation of a GUI application synchronous.
In the case at hand - for a GUI application that also reports a meaningful exit code - the **simplest solution is to *pipe to `Write-Output`***.

```
"About to install Python. "
# Note the `| Write-Output` at the end, which makes the invocation 
# synchronous and populates the $LASTEXITCODE variable.
c:/temp/python-3.11.4-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 InstallLauncherAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0 | Write-Output

# Check if the installation failed and exit, if so.
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
  Write-Error "Installation failed unexpectedly; exit code is $LASTEXITCODE."
  exit $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131324/45375) for an explanation of the technique, as well as alternatives.